JDBC SQL SERVER - Invalid column name
I don't understand at all what's wrong. I have Spring Boot app with JPA connected to SQL Server 2022. When I want to get all records, I call findAll from repository and have an error - invalid column name (for two columns). Both columns are exist. Checked SQL Profiler, and yes, SQL Server sends error, but If I copy past the same query what comes from JDBC, it works! I don't understand what's going on. Only things come in my head - encode, but I'm note sure.
RPC:Starting    
exec sp_executesql N'select n1_0.[id_news],n1_0.[ExpiryDate],n1_0.Html,n1_0.[Language],n1_0.NewsID,n1_0.Page from News n1_0'

Exception   Invalid column name 'id_news'.  
Exception   Invalid column name 'ExpiryDate'


Surely n1_0[id_news] should be n1_0.[id_news], no? Like wise for 2 of your other columns. n1_0[id_news] would return the column n1_0 and alias it as id_news. Surely you don't want to return the column n1_0 3 times with different aliases (not to mention that aliasing your table with a name of a column in that table is likely quite confusing).

@ThomA Sorry, this is my mistake of editing. There are dots.

Honestly, the most common reason is user error, and you are connected to the wrong database/instance (such as Production, instead of Dev, and Production is behind Dev and doesn't have the column(s) you're looking for). You then check the correct environment in a different tool, such as SSMS, and "validate" the columns are there, but it's not in the environment you are actually connecting to from the application code.

Are you able to print out the pure sql query which is submited to sql server?

Checked many times. Also I'm profiling the same database. When I call it from Spring app - it's called via RPC (remote procedure call) and I have the error. If I copy the same code from RPC to SQL editor and click run - works perfect. And both calls I see in profiler

@Reporter exec sp_executesql N'select n1_0.[id_news],n1_0.[ExpiryDate],n1_0.Html,n1_0.[Language],n1_0.NewsID,n1_0.Page from News n1_0 - this is what I see in profiler, what was called by JDBC as remote stored procedure. If copy the same code to editor - works perfectly

Do you run with same sql user? maybe can be some sort of schema thing going on. We can't help you cause we don't sit in from of your computer but it's obviously some kind of mixup that you need to correct

Good point on the schema, @siggemannen . FoxNet, you should always be schema qualifying your objects. So not FROM News but FROM <Schema Name>.News (such as dbo.News).

@siggemannen ThomA Guys. you were right!!! It was an access related error! But wtf ? Why instead of tell me - no access, or no table, it was issue with only two columns? If I remove these columns from select, no errors, but empty result? Also interesting, that MS SQL Managment studio even if I login with credentials (what I use for app), also added NTUser with admin rights, thats why I had no problem when I manually exucted script. Can some one me also explain why alll these things works in this way?

What does: select * from sys.objects where name = 'News' return when you execute with an admin user?

@siggemannen oh my god.  You are genius. Thank you very much. Yes, sys.objects had two tables with name news but different schema. Looks like ORM when didn't find a real table because no access, created new table in default schema for app db user... That's why I all the time worked with wrong table. We have a lot of tables in db, so it was difficult to see that new table. Thank you very much!
